# N X 3 matrix shorting and unique element matrix extraction

Tags: c++, matrix, short

I am facing problem with a 2D matrix consist of 3 column and N rows. Now I wanted to sort the matrix in such a way that the smallest of the first row is the first element, and so on. The first element of the second row is the smallest number with the smallest value of the first row. and similar to 3rd row. For example,

```
A    B   C
5   2    6
6   5    8
2   9    4
4   5    8
2   3    5
2   9    2
```

so the sorted matrix will be

```
A   B   C
2   3   5
2   9   2
2   9   4
4   5   8
5   2   6
6   5   8
```

Also, it will store the index of them such that

```
A_i  B_i  C_i

5     5    5 
6     6    6
3     3    3
```

and so on...

I implemented this using C++ which is not computationally efficient and takes so much time for a very big matrix. How I can Implement this a computationally efficient way and fast?

My current C++ code for the same is as follow

```
for(int tii=0; tii<f_sizee; tii++){
    track_index(tii)=tii+1;
    }

    for(int chkhk=0;chkhk<f_sizee;chkhk++){
        if(check_index(chkhk)==1){
            for(int chkhk1=chkhk+1;chkhk1<f_sizee;chkhk1++){
                 if((Va_mat(chkhk,0)==Va_mat(chkhk1,0))&&(Va_mat(chkhk,1)==Va_mat(chkhk1,1))&&(Va_mat(chkhk,2)==Va_mat(chkhk1,2))){
                     check_index(chkhk1)=0;
                     track_index(chkhk1)=seed_ind;
                    }
                    else track_index(chkhk)=seed_ind;
                }
                seed_ind=seed_ind+1;
            }
    }

    int new_dim=sum(check_index);
    int new_count=0;
    mat unsort_vmat=zeros(new_dim,Va_mat.n_cols);

    for(int iij=0; iij<f_sizee; iij++){
        if(check_index(iij)==1){
            unsort_vmat.row(new_count)=Va_mat.row(iij);
            new_count++;
        }
    }

    mat sort_vmat=zeros(new_dim,Va_mat.n_cols);
    uvec indices = stable_sort_index(unsort_vmat.col(0));
    int contrrS=0;
    for(int sort_f=0; sort_f < new_dim; sort_f++){
            for(uword sort_f2=0; sort_f2 < Va_mat.n_cols; sort_f2++){
                contrrS=indices(sort_f);
                sort_vmat(sort_f,sort_f2)=unsort_vmat(contrrS,sort_f2);
            }
    }

    mat sort_vmat2 = zeros(new_dim,Va_mat.n_cols);
    sort_vmat2 = sort_vmat ;
    double element_tmp=0;

    for(int iitr=0; iitr < new_dim; iitr++){
        for(int iitk=iitr; iitk < new_dim; iitk++){
            if(sort_vmat(iitk,0)==sort_vmat(iitr,0)){
                if(sort_vmat(iitk,1)>sort_vmat(iitr,1)){///if error, delete this brace
                    element_tmp=sort_vmat(iitr,1);
                    sort_vmat(iitr,1)=sort_vmat(iitk,1);
                    sort_vmat(iitk,1)=element_tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vec new_ind=zeros(f_sizee);
    int start_ind=0;
    for(int new_index=0; new_index<f_sizee; new_index++){
        new_ind(new_index)=start_ind;
        start_ind++;
    }
    int itr_count=0;
    for(uword itr1=0; itr1<Va_mat.n_rows; itr1++){
        for(int itr2=0; itr2<new_dim; itr2++){
            if((Va_mat(itr1,0)==sort_vmat2(itr2,0))&&(Va_mat(itr1,1)==sort_vmat2(itr2,1))&&(Va_mat(itr1,2)==sort_vmat2(itr2,2))){
                new_ind(itr_count)=itr2+1;
                itr_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    int funda=0;
    for(unsigned int Faa=0; Faa<Fa_mat.n_rows; Faa++){
        for(unsigned int Fab=0; Fab<Fa_mat.n_cols; Fab++){
            Fa_mat(Faa, Fab)=new_ind(funda);
            funda++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say you have a matrix consisting of "3 rows and N columns", but all your examples show 3 columns and more than 3 rows.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edit the question It is 3 rows and N columns.

Comment: When you say "short", you mean "sort", do you? Please, edit the question to include a [mre].

Comment: It sounds like you just want to sort rows of the matrix in lexicographical order. It's not clear how the code you show is related to that problem. Which of the numerous variables in that code represents the matrix to be sorted? What is the type of that variable?

Comment: When you say "it will store the index of them", what is "it" and who are "them"? I don't understand that part of the question at all.

Comment: @Bob__ It is actually "sort" (Thank you)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is actually a subsection of my FEM code. "It" refers to a matrix which stores the index of the matrix ("Them"). Actually my code is working but it is not an efficient way.  Also, yes I wanted to sort the matrix in lexicographical order (thank you to point out the exact technical term).